# Significance of Query weight in Cosine similarity

Tags: python, machine-learning, information-retrieval, cosine-similarity, data-retrieval

**QUESTION**

This is the algorithm i came across:

```
COSINESCORE(q)
1 float Scores[N] = 0 
2 Initialize Length[N] 
3 for each query term t 
4 do calculate *w(t,q)* and fetch postings list for t 
5 for each pair(d, tf(t,d) ) in postings list
6 do Scores[d] += w(t,d) × w(t,q) 
7 Read the array Length[d] 
8 for each d
9 do Scores[d] = Scores[d]/Length[d] 
10 return Top K components of Scores[]
```

1. In line 4,What is the use of calculating weight of query `w(t,q)` for cosine score calculations
2. How do i go about calculating it?

**Elaboration on what i don't understand**

Eg: if query="Data Scientist"
then,

```
tf = 1+log(1/2)        #1 For Count of "Data"
idf = log(N/df)
wtq = tf * idf           #w(t,q) here t="Data"
```

but in calculating idf, what is value of N(TotalNoOfDocuments) and df(DocFreq)

logically N=1 and df=1 but then idf=0 => wtq=0

Comment: N is a total number of documents in your corpora against which you're running your search query (since you want to find documents that are most relevant to your "Data Scientist" query in some corpora, not just in the short query) and df is the number of documents in your corpora which actually contain the term you're looking for (e.g., "Data" in your example so df = number of all the documents in your coprora that do contain "Data" term).